# Adding Sendgrid and Outlook SPF records to domain dns settings

Tags: outlook, dns, sendgrid, spf

I am recently having trouble with delivering my mail to Hotmail servers, and I noticed that SendGrid SPF is not set up on my DNS. Currently, in my DNS settings, I have an SPF setup out, as my domain emails are sent by outlook.

I have a TXT record with the Name:`example.com` and Value: `v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`

Now if I want to add a SendGrid SPF do I simply just add a new record:

Name: `example.com`
Value: `v=spf1 a include:sendgrid.net -all`

My DNS host is also **Cloudflare**

Or do I need to somehow combine these? Basically the issue I'm facing is the outlook is blocking my emails from its recipients and I am trying to add an SPF record to hopefully be authenticated.

Comment: In the case of SendGrid, you don't actually have to add any new record for SPF. When you add a new domain they provide few records to be added, SPF is also included within that as CNAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to combine them, like this:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:sendgrid.net -all
```

That said, your original record is a bit unusual record as it says that you only send through either outlook or sendgrid, so for example it means that a web server for your domain would not be able to send directly, and would also have to be configured to relay through those services too. If that's the way you want it, that's fine, but I thought I'd mention it. Similarly, it's common to include an `mx` mechanism in your SPF, as that says that anything that can receive mail for your domain can also send. To include both those options as well, it would change to this:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:sendgrid.net -all
```

Comment: Okay, I see how it works. I included that since when I set up my emails for my domain it was in the instruction manual of Outlook, but I do not know whether I cannot remove it or not. If I remove that will it affect the functionality of the mail servers?

Comment: If your domain uses outlook for sending your regular email, it needs to be in your SPF. Your SPF needs to cover **all** sources of email for your domain, and your `-all` says that anywhere not listed should be rejected.

Comment: Is your send grid mail from domain a subdomain? If so, then having sendgrid in the spf for your organizational d9main won’t help. The envelop from with sendgrid is usually a subdomain, whereas the header from is usually the organizations domain.